# MacBook Pro - FaceTime HD Camera - Hardware "Failure'?

Tags: hardware, camera, facetime

System Report>Camera>No video capture devices were found

> USB>Device Tree> No FaceTime HD Camera (inbuilt)listed

What can be the cause for "camera hardware failure"? Could faulty iSight cam wifi antenna cable linkage between logic board and camera board (in display)result in Camera hardware not "found"?

Answer (score 2):

It could be the cable or the connector on the logic board.

[image: 2009 MacBook Pro WiFi iSight Connector]

In my experience, the most likely place the damage will occur is where the cable that combines Wi-Fi and the camera come together into a single connector or it will be the connector on the logic board itself.  It's highly unlikely that the cable/connector at the iSight camera will become damaged unless repairs were done there previously.

Now, it's also entirely possible that your camera has failed (especially if Wi-Fi is still working.)

There are a few ways to diagnose this, but this involves using another cable and/or iSight camera.  If you don't have these items handy or you're not willing to purchase them (or perform this type of task), it's probably best that you take it in for service.

Comment: Apart from the camera not detected issue, the wifi is also "unstable", shifting from "ON >Looking for Networks" . Wifi can connect to network only if it is within 3' from the router. Could the joint "failure" of wifi and camera be caused by a faulty (joint) iSight cam /wifi antenna cable?

Comment: It's a good possibility.  You may have a loose or bad connection in either the cable or the connector on the logic board.  The only way to find out for certain is to use a different cable, but before installing it properly, just connect everything up - if the problem goes away, it's your cable, if not, it's the connector.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a bad connection to the logic board or a shorted wire could result in hardware not being found. You should have this taken in to an Apple store to have it diagnosed.